# How to exclude redundant validation errors for pydantic fields which allow empty dict as value?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have following models

```
from typing import Union

from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra, Field
from typing_extensions import Annotated, Literal


class Empty(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid


class ModelX(BaseModel):
    member: Literal["x"]
    q: str


class ModelY(BaseModel):
    member: Literal["y"]
    q: None


class MainModel(BaseModel):
    model: Union[Annotated[Union[ModelX, ModelY], Field(discriminator="member")], Empty]


MainModel.parse_obj({"model": {}})
MainModel.parse_obj({"model": {"member": "x", "q": None}})
```

Since None `q` is not allowed for `ModelX` I am getting following error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for MainModel
model -> ModelX -> q
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
model -> member
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
model -> q
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

But, I do not need last 2 messages, since it is not empty dict and I do not expect it.

Comment: But you allowed the `Empty` model as a type for the `model` field as well. How is Pydantic supposed to know that you _meant_ to provide data that can be parsed as `ModelX`/`ModelY` and _not_ as `Empty`? It will try each type in the type union until one of them parses successfully. When none of them do, it produces the errors for each of them. I think that makes perfect sense to be honest.

Comment: Though I don't know the context, your schema using a _kinda-sorta-discriminated-union-but-not-really_ seems very strange to me. I would question the reasoning behind the way `model` is typed and assume this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg could you elaborate a bit on you last comment? Why it is not really discriminated union? Actually it was a single model before, but since for member with value x allowed to be str, and for y it should be none, I think what union with discriminator is okay

Comment: OK, I mean the fact that the type of `MainModel.model` is a union of an actual discriminated union and `Empty`. Can you explain why you think you need to allow a value of the type `Empty` for that field? Or what the purpose of `Empty` even is at all? Because I cannot imagine a situation where that may be useful.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg the purpose of that is just to allow empty dict w/o any fileds for `model` field as well. So allowed values for `model` are `{}`, `{'member': 'x', 'q': 'str_value'}`, `{'member': 'y', 'q': None}`

Comment: That is not an explanation of the purpose, that just a description of what we can see from the schema already. Anyway, regardless of whether this setup makes sense or not, my first comment still stands. The error is perfectly reasonable and those last two messages are _not_ redundant because your data is also checked against that `Empty` model. Pydantic cannot know what you _mean_. It can only check all available options and tell you why none of them worked.

Comment: The purpose is to be able accept `{}` empty dict as well some structured data. That is 3rd party requirement, dunno is there any way how to express it on pydantic models